# tikz - translate svg Bézier curve to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to translate below svg code to tikz (in comment) but looks like output is totally different:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5,y=0.5]
        % M 420 300 C 500.88888888888886 280 600.4444444444445 260 700 240
   \draw (420,300) .. controls (500.89,280) and (600.44,260) ..(700,240);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The original svg graph is from [here](https://www.particleincell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/circles.svg)!
My tikz output is:
[image]

Comment: You have four points on your picture and only two in your Bezier curve. Are you sure you got everything right from the SVG?

Comment: Indeed there is only one line segment in your code (the third one). The shape looks ok, only the slope is reversed. The full code I get from inspecting the svg is `M 60 60 C 111.55555555555557 160 163.11111111111114 260 220 300` for the first line, `M 220 300 C 276.88888888888886 340 339.11111111111114 320 420 300` for the second line and your code for the third line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you get when you extract all datas from your SVG file:

[image: svg to tikz]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}        
   \draw[line width=1pt,cyan,scale=0.1]
        (6,6) node[dot]{} .. controls (11.15,16) and (16.3,26) ..
        (22,30) node[dot]{} .. controls (27.7,34) and (33.9,32) ..
        (42,30) node[dot]{} .. controls (50,28) and (60,26) ..
        (70,24) node[dot]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

I divided all numbers by ten.
Note that the slope is inverted, you can change this by adding `yscale=-1`:

[image: mirrored]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}        
   \draw[line width=1pt,cyan,scale=0.1,yscale=-1]
        (6,6) node[dot]{} .. controls (11.15,16) and (16.3,26) ..
        (22,30) node[dot]{} .. controls (27.7,34) and (33.9,32) ..
        (42,30) node[dot]{} .. controls (50,28) and (60,26) ..
        (70,24) node[dot]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I view the svg from browser but the dot is generated by code, how do you get the path from the svg file?

Comment: On a browser, right click on your curve and select *inspect*. Then you have the svg commands (which are plain text). Three `path` commands for the curves and four `circle` commands for the nodes.